# scope binding not resolving in google app engine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-app-engine, angularjs-scope

I am creating a website with AngularJS.
In my view, I have a file called `menu.html` which is responsible for displaying navigation bar:

```
<div class="container">
   <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li ng-repeat="menu in navigation" class="{{menu.classis}}"><a href="{{menu.link}}">{{menu.name}}</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The following code works properly on my desktop, but when hosted on google-app engine the navigation bar is not being displayed.

It is unable to resolve `{{menu.classis}}` and `{{menu.link}}`

what is the problem?

I am new to angularjs and google app engine, so I may not be using correctly terminology.
The link to the hosted website: http://libinelectricals.appspot.com

Answer (score 0):

The html snippet you have included is from your browser, not the source. Your source contains an extra closing `</ul>` which is breaking the page layout.

```
<div class="container">


   <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li ng-repeat="menu in navigation" class=""><a href=""></a>
    </li>
</ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I can see the menu there now - not sure if it was related to this fix or something different.

Comment: I put that manually without any binding. Actually if you see the footer even there i have used a binding for getting the current year, even that is not getting displayed.
Spent so much time, i'm not getting anything.
It is working properly locally

Comment: Looking at your footer, there is no indication you're attempting to bind using angular. You don't have something like mustache or handlebars processing on the server?